# Dupe question... but answers are extremely different

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, exact-duplicates

I recently asked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/373200/90136) about disabling Siri entirely in the touch bar on the new Macbook Pro models. The question is [technically a duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258816/how-to-completely-disable-siri-on-sierra) (and was marked as such), however the answers on the dupe all use terminal/editing of config files as opposed to using System Preferences to control the touch bar.

My guess is that the dupe target was *before* Apple made it possible to nicely edit the touch bar (System Preference --> Keyboard --> Customize Touch Bar).

So while the dupe question is the same, the answers there no longer really apply to editing the touch bar since now there is an actual customization menu that Apple introduced. Should this be unmarked as a duplicate, or merged in some way (e.g. [Danill's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373204/90136) migrated to the dupe)?

Question *and* answers considered, I don't believe this is a dupe, but it's really close so I'm not sure what to do here...

Comment: Thanks for bringing your question to Meta for discussion!  Take a look at [this answer from a similar issue](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2272/88313) as to what you're asking (I guess, technically, your question here could be marked as a duplicate of that question).  I think the answer provided there will give you the guidance you need.  If not, please come back here and let us know why it will not work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Touch Bar model, so using the menu bar as equivalent.

Your question has a mismatch between the title and the concluding question. The title invites questions in "Linked" items which later lead to the target question.

It should have been "How can I remove the Siri icon in the touch bar?" or similar. This would be similar to someone asking how to remove it from the menu bar. Which is different from disabling it completely. I use Siri, using hold <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. But I have removed it from Menu bar.

I am not a diamond moderator. I won't support merging them. One is very particular about activity monitor and disables Siri in a way that everyone doesn't necessarily want. That is my impression from your question.

They can be linked in comments as a milder alternative, but moving Danill's answer there will at best invite downvotes.

So I suggest you edit the question title and I will vote to [reopen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: Done! Question title has been edited, now it is definitely *not* a dupe, so I believe it should be re-opened.